# T-SQL - Generate rows from Field with Number

Tags: sql-server

I have a Table with the following Fields:

```
----------------------------------------
| Start Date        | Recurrences      |
----------------------------------------
| 01-01-2015        | 12               |
----------------------------------------
| 01-06-2015        | 10               |
----------------------------------------
```

What I need to output is a total of 22 rows (12 + 10). Each row should contain the 'Start Date' field plus the increment of days depending on which recurrence.

I was able to generate a number of rows with an increment using this table of SQL Server:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT n = number 
FROM 
    master..[spt_values] 
WHERE 
    number BETWEEN 1 AND 1000
```

But what I need is to trigger this select per each row of my table and set the MAX to **Recurrences** field and not to **1000**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're multiplying, a simple inner join should do:

```
select
 Number,
 StartDate
from YourTable
inner join master..[spt_values] on number between 1 and YourTable.Recurrences
```

Comment: So easy ... I think I need more coffe. Thanks work perfect